# How to remove unwanted <p> tags from WordPress editor using TinyMCE?

Tags: wordpress, tags, tinymce

I am using WordPress editor TinyMCE. I have something like this:

```
<div class="TA_excellent" id="TA_excellent150"><ul>...</ul></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=excellent&amp;uniq=150&amp;locationId=287500&amp;lang=en_AU">
</script>
```

When I skipped to visual editor "script" tags are removed from the content. So I tried every kind plugin including Ultimate TinyMCE but this time "script" tags are wrapped by "p" tags.

So output is something like this:

```
...</ul></div>
    <p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=excellent&amp;uniq=150&amp;locationId=287500&amp;lang=en_AU">
    </script>
    <script src="http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/WidgetEmbed-excellent?uniq=150&amp;locationId=287500&amp;lang=en_AU"></script
    </p>
```

I also tried plugin called "Advanced TinyMCE Settings" it allows me to change the default TinyMCE configuration. My config under TinyMCE settings is like this:

```
  extended_valid_elements:  script[type|src],a[*]
```

I spent hours and hours on it just won't work. I can't get rid of this "p" tags. They keep continue to publish automatically.

Here are screenshots from Ultimate TinyMCE:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Removing unwanted p and br tags (empty ) can be done by adding simple filter function to theme functions.php
Here is the code you need to add.

```
function remove_additional_p($content){
  $content = forec_balance_tags($content);
  return preg_replace('#<p>\s*+(<br\s*/*>)?|s*</p>#i','',$content);
}


add_filter('the_content','remove_additional_p',20,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to remove **`<p></p>`** before editor initialize.

```
function tinymce_remove_root_block_tag( $init ) {
    $init['forced_root_block'] = false; 
    return $init;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinymce_remove_root_block_tag' );
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be done without code.

Go to `Settings` > `TINYMCE Advanced` and check
 **Stop removing the `<p>` and `<br />` tags when saving and show them in the HTML editor**

[image]

Whereas it is bad practice to put scripts in your text area, well you can remove `<p>` tags by doing this:

```
$text=str_ireplace('<p>','',$post->post_conent);
$text=str_ireplace('</p>','',$post->post_conent);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I installed TINYMCE Advanced and checked "Stop removing the <p> and <br /> tags" option. Nothing changed. "script" tags are still being wrapped by "p" tags.

Comment: should I put this in my function.php under my theme?

Comment: Sorry didn't work either. I have only activcated TINYMCE Advanced  plugin at the moment.