# Wordpress adds <p> and <br> tags to Visual View in editor

Tags: wordpress

In the rich textarea of a form in a wordpress application, only the visual mode is enabled, we type in text and save it, then it takes us to the edit post page where it shows the saved text in the textarea together with

and 
(if any)  tags, this is not desirable, I think this should only show in the Text view, not the Visual View.

How does one solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not clear to me, can you please add more details, screenshots ?

Comment: Try asking this question on the [WordPress StackExchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @Milap I mean the Visual section of tinymce editor shows html code instead of the formatted output, how do I get rid of the code-html tags

Comment: @bodesam maybe you could take some screen shots to demonstrate what you mean and help us understand - step by step.

Comment: Thanks, I've added screenshots, the first is the Visual View with <p> tags that are not supposed to be there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove unwanted p tags from wordpress editor tinymce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464028/how-to-remove-unwanted-p-tags-from-wordpress-editor-tinymce)